# HSQLDB indices and multi-column constraints

Tags: sql, hsqldb

The manual says "Indexes should not duplicate the columns of PRIMARY KEY, UNIQUE or FOREIGN key constraints as each of these constraints creates an index automatically." It is unclear to me whether that applies also to individual columns of a multi-column constraint. Say I have a unique constraint on columns (A,B) and I plan to do selects on B, do I need an index on B?

Answer (score 1):

The quoted bit is from chapter 4. The answer can be found in chapter 2: "n HyperSQL 2.0, a multi-column index will speed up queries that contain joins or values on the first n columns of the index. You need NOT declare additional individual indexes on those columns unless you use queries that search only on a subset of the columns." So in my scenario I would need an extra index on B but I could obviate the need by making the uniqueness constraint be on (B,A) instead of (A,B).